# How to traverse nested objects to find value with vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

So I am working on creating a real-time search box that will search the name of nested objects. I'm having a hard time traversing the objects to find the value of the "name" key. For example:

```
const colors = {
  blues: {
    "Neutral Blue": {
      name: "Blue", //looking to search at this depth
    },

    "Dark Blue": {
      name: "Navy",
    },

    "Light Blue": {
      name: "Azure",
    },

    "Green Blue": {
      name: "Teal",
    },
  },

  greens: {
    "Light Green": {
      name: "Seafoam",
    },

    "Blueish Green": {
      name: "Mint",
    },

    "Grey Green": {
      name: "sage",
    },
  },

  reds: {
    "Light Red": {
      name: "blush",
    },
    "Neutral Red": {
      name: "Scarlett",
    },
    "Dark Red": {
      name: "Merlot",
    },
  },
};
```

I'm trying to traverse:

1. `colors` variable =>
2. Parent color category
3. object name
4. Find `name:` key and finally:
5. get value from `name` key.

My ultimate goal is to search all of these values to return a realtime search result. Any way I can do this using vanilla JS?

I tried using standard methods like `Object.values(colors)`, but I cannot figure out how to skip over object key value pairs. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

---

**Edit:**

I'm trying to find a cleaner output of the following:

```
let names = Object.entries(colors);

names.map((n) => {
  let name = Object.values(n[1]).forEach((value) => console.log(value));
});


//returns:

Object { name: "Blue" }
Object { name: "Navy" }
Object { name: "Azure" }
Object { name: "Teal" }
Object { name: "Seafoam" }
Object { name: "Mint" }
Object { name: "sage" }
Object { name: "blush" }
Object { name: "Scarlett" }
Object { name: "Merlot" }
```

Comment: What parameters are you using to search?

Comment: I'm trying to use the `indexOf()` method to match input text on a `keyup` event.

Comment: Could you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63405446/edit) to provide some sample input / search values and examples of the result you want for each

Comment: What are you searching for the object based on? The key?

Comment: Sure! Just edited my question for a little more clarity. @hev1, I'm looking for the `name` key, and want to get the value of that.

Comment: @Sackadelic You want an array of all the `name`s?

Comment: Yeah, that sample doesn't make a lot of sense. For one, it doesn't _return_ anything. I'll ask again, given an input value or values, what **exactly** should the result be (in as valid a JS structure as possible please)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

If you are using modern browsers you can use this to get array of the names

```
Object.values(colors)
.flatMap(x => Object.values(x))
.map(x => x.name);
```

Then search inside the returned array.
[about flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Comment: @Sackadelic if you have specific browser compatibility requirements, please state them in your question